# How to automatically restart delayed_job when deploying a rails project on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-web-services, delayed-job, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm hosting a rails project on [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/en/elasticbeanstalk/) and I try to configure a [container command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) to automatically restart my [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) worker on the server after each deployment.

I tried with this one :

```
container_commands:
  restartdelayedjob:
    command: "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pid-dir=/home/ec2-user/pids start"
    cwd: /var/app/current
```

But, it seems that the pushed version is deployed after the restarting of the worker so the jobs failed to be processed by the worker.

When I connect on my instance by ssh, kill the worker process and restart a new one from the deployed version folder, everything works fine.

Do you have any ideas of how I can handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As per the [Amazon documentation for `container_commands`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands):

> They run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version file has been extracted, but **before the application version is deployed**.

(emphasis mine)

This means at that point `/var/app/current` which you are setting as the `cwd` for your command is still pointing to the previous version.  However by default, from the docs again, `cwd`:

> is the directory of the unzipped application.

This means that if you want to run `delayed_job` from the directory of the app that just got extracted (but not yet deployed), don't override `cwd` and it should start the delayed_job for the app that's about to be deployed.

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands

### Update:

I've now set this up myself and found there's limitations to doing it via the standard `container_commands` - basically delayed_job will be started while it is still in the `/var/app/ondeck` directory. Usually this is OK, but I had some issues with some jobs because that path had stuck around it would cause errors as the app was now in `/var/app/current`.

I found an undocumented (so warning!) approach that you can add scripts to be run AFTER your app server is restarted (and your new deploy is in `/var/app/current`).

Basically Elastic Beanstalk will execute any scripts in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post` after the web server is restarted. This means if you drop shell scripts in this directory they will be run.

I created a shell script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT
su -c "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pid-dir=$EB_CONFIG_APP_SUPPORT/pids restart" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
```

I uploaded this script to an S3 bucket, and made sure it was "public". You can then use an options script in your `.ebextensions` directory (eg. `99delayed_job.config`) to deploy this script as part of your app deploy, taking note that the `post` directory might not exist:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: http://YOUR_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/99_restart_delayed_job.sh
```

When you deploy you should see something like this in your `/var/log/eb-tools.log`:

```
2013-05-16 01:20:53,759 [INFO] (6467 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing directory: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/
2013-05-16 01:20:53,760 [INFO] (6467 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh
2013-05-16 01:21:02,619 [INFO] (6467 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: delayed_job: trying to stop process with pid 6139...
delayed_job: process with pid 6139 successfully stopped.

2013-05-16 01:21:02,620 [INFO] (6467 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
```

As I said, putting stuff in this "post" directory is undocumented - but hopefully at some point Amazon add actual support to the `.options` scripts to run commands post-deploy, in that case you could move this to the officially supported approach.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me too. Just some considerations:
- If you're using rails 4, modify shell script to execute bin/delayed_job instead of script/delayed_job;
- I have to add this (chmod +x bin/delayed_job) after line cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT on script. Was getting permission error;
- If you're getting "no such file or directory" error when executing script you may have to add some lines on your .ebextensions .config file. Add dos2unix package install and the command dos2unix /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh

Comment: @Marcin If you have several instances behind a load balancer, doesn't this start the background job in every instance? Is there a way to run the background job in only one instance? Or where do you intend to run this code. A background worker?

Comment: @King'oriMaina - yes, it starts the job on every instance, but delayed_job (and I assume most queueing systems) will lock the job they're working on so there's no duplication, and the work is distributed. With EB you can have a command only run on the "leader", so look into that if you only want to run on one instance.

Comment: @Marcin Figured, thanks for the confirmation. I know about running on the leader but that option only exists in `container_commands` and not the `files` configuration options on EB.

Comment: This seems to have problems in the latest EB Ruby container, see error here ... ['How to get fix 'require' errors when setting up delayed_job on Elastic Beanstalk'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164607/how-to-get-fix-require-errors-when-setting-up-delayed-job-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: What's with the magic 99 numbering, why not 1 or 79, and can we do 109? I see ninety-something in a few places but no-one explains it!

Answer (score 6):

On **64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.1.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Passenger Standalone)**, got it working thanks to [this post](http://www.dannemanne.com/posts/post-deployment_script_on_elastic_beanstalk_restart_delayed_job).

Note that this script is run as root, but your workers should be run as the webapp user.

```
# Adds a post-deploy hook such that after a new version is deployed
# successfully, restarts the delayed_job workers.
#
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401204/how-to-automatically-restart-delayed-job-when-deploying-a-rails-project-on-amazo
# http://www.dannemanne.com/posts/post-deployment_script_on_elastic_beanstalk_restart_delayed_job
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_delayed_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
      EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
      EB_APP_PIDS_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_pid_dir)

      . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
      . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

      cd $EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR

      # Switch to the webapp user.  Worker shouldn't be run as root.
      su -s /bin/bash -c "bundle exec bin/delayed_job --pid-dir=$EB_APP_PIDS_DIR restart" $EB_APP_USER
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody is looking to get delayed_job working in latest ElasticBeanstalk (64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)): I got it to work using the below code (Thanks to [damontorgerson](https://gist.github.com/damontorgerson/2231f42302da9f9f078b)). This file goes in ruby.config in .ebextensions folder.

```
# Install git in order to be able to bundle gems from git
packages:
yum:
  git: []

files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_delayed_job":
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
      EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir)
      EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      EB_CONFIG_APP_LOGS=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_log_dir)
      EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
      EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
      EB_CONFIG_APP_PIDS=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_pid_dir)

      . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
      . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

      cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT

      . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars.d/sysenv

      bin/delayed_job --pid-dir=/var/tmp restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I got mine working like so with the "daemons" gem:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
  webapp_pids:
    command: "mkdir /home/webapp/pids"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
      chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp/pids
      su -l -c "$EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT/bin/delayed_job --pid-dir=/home/webapp/pids restart" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
      echo "worker starting" >> /var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log
```