# Deploy yeoman node.js application to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, yeoman, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS application that I developed using a Yeoman generator that I'm attempting to deploy to an Elastic Beanstalk instance. I'm fairly new to this stack so my apologies if the question seems scattered. I was able to deploy my application using this process: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html. However, when I hit my homepage I just have a blank Node application. I'm guessing this is because the deploy comes straight from my Git repository and my Grunt build process hasn't been run. Is there any way to tell Elastic Beanstalk to run Grunt build after receiving the deployable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to setup Grunt to run with a deployment hook on AWS. This is done with [container commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands).

Checkout this answer: [How to automatically restart delayed_job when deploying a rails project on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401204/how-to-automatically-restart-delayed-job-when-deploying-a-rails-project-on-amazo/16275837#16275837)

And this relevant blog post: http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/