# Apache Solr failing to connect to Django Elastic Beanstalk server

Tags: python, django, solr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup an elastic beanstalk instance with Django and am trying to use Apache Solr to index products in the application. Solr is running as a background process as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126387/automatically-setup-apache-solr-with-django-oscar-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/34279331#34279331), but the server is returning a 500 error for all requests. Looking at the logs in /etc/httpd/error_log, there is an error:

```
Failed to query Solr using '*:*': Failed to connect to server at 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select/?facet.query=price...' 
('connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

In my Django settings.py, I have the haystack settings for Solr as follows: (from [here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/docs/source/howto/how_to_setup_solr.rst))

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}
```

Looking at the code for Solr on [github](https://github.com/calvinchengx/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py):

```
        try:
            raw_results = self.conn.search(query_string, **kwargs)
        except (IOError, SolrError), e:
            if not self.silently_fail:
                raise
            self.log.error("Failed to query Solr using '%s': %s", query_string, e)
        raw_results = EmptyResults()
```

I checked the security group settings on AWS, and the group accepts inbound traffic on port 8983 (from within that group). Also, I ssh into the EC2 instance, and the Solr java process is running in the background. Looking at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-haystack/JsMoxV70M6w) post, it seems that Haystack is defaulting to the local Database settings, and not the AWS Elastic Beanstalk settings.

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'hhwc',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

What could cause this 500 server error (connection error with Solr)?

Comment: did you ssh the server and made sure solr is responding on port 8983? (telnet localhost 8983)

Comment: Telnet is refusing connections on 8983, however, the Solr process is running in the background.