# Correct way to run manage.py commands after deployment on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Django app to EB - my first EB deployment - and I'm confused about the order of things.

My container commands are these:

```
container_commands:
   01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
   02_collectstatic:
     command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
     leader_only: true
```

What I've noticed, however, is that each time I deploy, these container commands are run on my *old* codebase. Suppose my current code is `app-v1.zip`. I update my `models.py`, and create a migration. I then `eb deploy`, which creates `app-v2.zip`. The `migrate` command is run on the EB environment, but is run on the old codebase (`app-v1.zip`), before `app-v2.zip` is unpacked into `/var/app/current`, and so my migration isn't applied.

If I then run another `eb deploy`, it will create `app-v3.zip`, but will run `migrate` on the code in `app-v2.zip`. So, it works, but it means I have to run `eb deploy` twice any time I want to change either data models or static files (the same issue applies to `collectstatic`).

There is more explanation and a workaround [on this blog post](http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401204/how-to-automatically-restart-delayed-job-when-deploying-a-rails-project-on-amazo/16275837#16275837), but all the "deploy Django to EB" tutorials do things the way I've done it with `container_commands`.

What's the correct way?

Comment: Are you sure? I have been using EB for a year and I have never seen the behavior you describe. The blog talks about the fact that the commands get run on a staging area before deployment but that staging area should have your new archive. Can you give more details on how you think this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made me worry, but I have confirmed that `eb deploy` does run the commands with the new version of the code. It does this on a staging area, before actually releasing to the server, but it does with the proper version.

You can do `eb logs -a` after the deployment and look for the `eb-activity.log` to see how all commands get executed, and the proper migration happens.

As for the flow, I prefer NOT to call collecstatics as part of the EB flow, as I am releasing that code directly into S3 (and CloudFront) using a gulp based flow. So, I just run migrate as part of the deployment (plus other things particular to my application):

```
 01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

and everything works as expected.